# How to have more than one set of data for Npgsql prepared statement?

Tags: database, vb.net, npgsql

**Below is my code for adding parameters in my vb .net code for prepared statements of Npgsql:**

```
Dim xConn As NpgsqlConnection = ConnectDB()
Dim xCmd As NpgsqlCommand = xConn.CreateCommand()
xCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE " & xTable & " SET previous_tot_adj = @prev_adj ,tot_adj = @tot_adj WHERE version = " & _version & " AND monthly_mq_id = @Index"
For Each Index In _Results.Keys
    If Not IsNothing(_Results.Item(Index)) Then
        xCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("prev_adj", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Double, _Results.Item(Index))
        xCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tot_adj", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Double, _Results.Item(Index))
        xCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Index", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bigint, Index)
    End If
Next
xCmd.Prepare()
xCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

After executing this code, I get this kind of error:

> A first chance exception of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlException' occurred in Npgsql.dll
>   ERROR: 08P01: bind message has 34193 parameter formats but 1 parameters

Can anyone enlighten me for what's wrong on what I'm doing?

Comment: Does that provider support "@" as a parameter prefix?  That is a Microsoft thing that the Connector/Net for MySQL has also supported for compatibility, even though MySQL itself doesn't.  I haven't checked but my first guess would be that PostgreSQL and the Npgsql provider don't support it.

Comment: Actually, I just checked and it looks like "@" is supported, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: I just adapted my code from Ado .Net in the Npgsql documentation from this link [Npgsql Prepared Statement](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/prepare.html)

Comment: What I'm trying to do here is to have more than one set of the three parameters _prev_adj,tot_adj,Index_ so for a normal sql statement it would be like this `UPDATE MyDbTable SET previous_tot_adj = 123 ,tot_adj = 123 WHERE version = 111 AND monthly_mq_id = 123;UPDATE MyDbTable SET previous_tot_adj = 123 ,tot_adj = 123 WHERE version = 111 AND monthly_mq_id = 123;`

Comment: As far as I'm aware, if you use "@" in the SQL statement, you need to use "@" in the name when adding the parameter to the command, which you're not.  E.g. I don't think that "Index" will be matched up with "@Index".

Comment: Also, why are you not using a parameter for `version`.?  Maybe it's not required but it's still best practice.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try adding "@" in the parameter.
I'm not using parameter on the `version` since it's a constant value but i'll try adding it as a parameter too.

Answer (score 0):

Ifound out the problem,i was using an outdated Npgsql. I jus installed the new verion v4.0.1 [NugetGallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/). This fixed the issue.